# Find Bible passages by keyword/ topic

Tags: bible, resource-request, books

I am chemistry and biology lecturer. When I teach new concepts such as equilibrium or origin of life or liquids, etc, sometimes I would like to check if there is some interesting passage in Bible that talks about that concept. Of course it is likely there will be something about equilibrium but not something directly related to molecules. The thing is I would like to find passages in the Bible with that concept/topic/keyword. I tried to use Google or similar tools but the results are not very good. Anybody can help with this?

Comment: Sorry but we don't do verse search questions here.

Comment: And where can I ask this ?

Comment: @curiousdannii he's not asking for a verse search here but for a tool to help in searching for verses. I don't think that's off-topic.

Comment: Since Bible topical dictionary typically doesn't include natural science concepts beyond the most general (like stars, water, heat, etc.) I would think your search is best served by looking for a book dedicated to a collection of Bible verses related to a particular discipline like Chemistry / Biology.  I once received a gift this book titled ["All the Music of the Bible"](https://www.amazon.com/All-Music-Bible-Herbert-Lockyer/dp/1565635310) containing not only all Bible verses related to music, but topical coverage of interest to musicians as well.

Answer (score 7):

Much to my surprise, when I keyed in the word ‘equilibrium’ into a Christian web site I frequently use, it came up with an article about ‘punctuated equilibrium’: https://www.gotquestions.org/punctuated-equilibrium.html

Another article I found was on DNA – not that you will find anything in the Bible specific to ‘deoxyribonucleic acid’.   The article presents a simple overview of the topic without delving into the complexities of the science:  https://www.gotquestions.org/DNA-Creator.html

The reason for my surprise in finding these articles is that this web site is dedicated to answering questions about Christianity and the Bible.  It is not intended as a scientific guide!  However, it also has links to a whole range of articles on scientific topics, some of which do quote relevant Bible verses.   Some of the topics discussed under the heading of Creation include abiogenesis, palingenesis, natural selection and evolution.  Below is a link to all the scientific topics this site covers:  https://www.gotquestions.org/questions_Creation.html

I am not trying to promote this particular Christian web site, but merely suggest it might be of some use to you.

P.S. These books may also be relevant but you would need a hard copy to find the Bible passages that are listed in the Chapter References and Notes section at the back:

Prof Edgar Andrews, BSc, PHD, DSc, FInstP, FIMMM, CEng, CPhys, is an expert in large molecules and Emeritus Professor of Materials at the University of London:

What is Man? Adam, Alien or Ape? - Edgar Andrews (Elm Hill 2018)

Who Made God? Searching for a theory of everything - Edgar Andrews (EP 2014)

Tom McLeish is Prof of Physics & pro-vice-chancellor for Research at Durham University.  He has awards for his research on the molecular theory of complex fluid flow. This book includes such knowledge when looking at biblical matters: Faith & Wisdom in Science - Tom McLeish (Oxford 2014)

Alister McGrath is a Prof of Science and Religion at Oxford University, qualified in the natural sciences and theology: Inventing the Universe – Why we can’t stop talking about Science, Faith and God - Alister McGrath pp 56, 58 (Hodder & Stoughton 2015)

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach that may yield fruit is to combine a direct Bible search tool such as [Biblegateway.com](http://www.biblegateway.com/) with keyword synonyms sourced from either a dictionary or a thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

OpenBible.info's [Topical Bible](https://www.openbible.info/topics/) is one such resource.